# Linux tail only whole words

Tags: bash, tail

I need to print last 20 characters of string, but only whole words. Delimiter is a space "". Let's consider this example:

> > string="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
> >     echo $string | tail -c20

returns `s over the lazy dog`. And I need it to return `over the lazy dog` instead. Do you know how to accomplish that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $string | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /\b(\S.{0,20})$/'
```

Comment: Using grep: echo $string | egrep -o '\<.{0,20}$'

Comment: @UdiM: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $string | rev | cut -d ' ' -f -20
```

Comment: That outputs the *first* twenty *words*.

Comment: lol... well spotted, changed it with rev, but it still wont work over muptiple lines... will research...

Answer (score 1):

This works in Bash > 3.2 without using any external programs:

```
[[ $string =~ \ (.{0,20})$ ]]
result="$BASH_REMATCH[1]"
```

I used **UdiM's** `grep` version as a basis.